# Eigenvector and corresponding Eigenvalue in Armadillo

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm using Armadillo in C++. I computed the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix A using the `eig_sym` function. Now I'd like to multiply an eigenvector v by its corresponding eigenvalue to compare it with A*v just to see that it worked correctly.
How do I do that? Eigenvalues are sorted in ascending order but the indices of the eigenvectors seem to not correspond to their corresponding eigenvalue.

Comment: I dont know armadillo, but once you multiply `A*v` you will see which eigenvalue `a` corresnponds to the eigenvector `v`, because `A*v = a*v`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai problem is i have hundreds of 500-dimensional vectors